# jquery table hovering from image area and map

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have a picture, one map. I would like that when there is `mouseover` in a specific zone (I used area and map tag), the cursor will become an html element (`img`, or text) and will be on highlighted the cell of table under (`tr`) of reference. And all the same from table hovering.

Below a link with example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ACKhM/3/

Hope your answer,
A.